# Limit number of table rows, based on screen size

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So, i have n objects in a collection. I'm using `ng-repeat` in a `<tr>`.

Is there a way to limit how many rows it will generate in the html, in way that the table does not exceed the current screen height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

You can get the height of element where you are creating the table. suppose the height is **300px**.
And you can get the height of row of table (`<td>`), say **30px**.

Now **№ of rows** that can be shown in the screen will be `300/30 = 10` (including the header).

So you can have ng-if on `$index == 10` (with the ng-repeat).

> The values will change as per your screen size.

Comment: is'nt this the container size and not screen size?, @Kabanossi what do you do with the rows your not displaying?

Comment: @Seabizkit: if the table is to be shown in screen then the contain could be <body>, and the rest of the rows can be shown with pagination.

Comment: there is a distinction between container height and screen height. Im not sure i follow " if the table is to be shown in screen then the contain could be <body>" so the table height is static and what the OP meant was container height and not screen, the title should be updated to reflect such.

Comment: @Seabizkit: correct, in case the screen size changes, there should be a function which watch that and update the number of rows to be shown. `window.addEventListener('resize', function () {...})` can be used to update the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can follow the following steps :

1. On screen prepared or View Loaded (Before data fetched from Server) Fix the Table height by calculating height like `( view-port height - header height - footer height - if any other)`
2. Write a CSS Rule with `Overflow : Auto` to enable auto scrolling as data exceeds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this by knowing table's `<td>` height and the screen size (window.screen.height).

```
numberOfRows = Math.floor(window.screen.height / tdHeight)
```